# how change location of status.txt and status2.txt in this code

Tags: batch-file, firewall

i have this batch code for firewall status and it work successfully.but when i want to change the location of status and status2 to the different location (for example desktop )it not work.please help

```
Netsh firewall show state > status.txt
Find /C "Operational mode                  = Enable" "status.txt" > 
status2.txt
For /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims= " %%a in (status2.txt) Do Set value2=%%a
Set value2=%value2:~23,1%
Del /F status.txt
Del /F status2.txt
If %value2%==0 exit
```

Comment: show us your changed (not working) code, so we can retrace your error

Answer (score 0):

`Set value2=%value2:~23,1%` strongly depends on filename lenght. Instead, [extract only last character in string](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) using `Set "value2=%value2:~-1%"`.

- Another approach: use *no auxiliary files*
- Bonus: no auxiliary files, no `for` loop

The script (note that `mode` environment variable injected merely for demonstration, see output; moreover, `If %value2%==0 exit` command omitted for debugging purposes):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
rem  EnableDelayedExpansion
set "mode=%~1"
if "%mode%"=="" set "mode=Enable"

rem ancestral approach improved
Netsh firewall show state > "%temp%\status.txt"
Find /C "Operational mode                  = %mode%" "%temp%\status.txt" > "%temp%\status2.txt"
For /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%temp%\status2.txt") Do Set "value2=%%a"
Set "value2=%value2:~-1%"
Del /F "%temp%\status.txt"
Del /F "%temp%\status2.txt"
echo  2 files, find   : value2=[%value2%]

rem with no auxiliary files
set "value2="
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('
  Netsh firewall show state^|Find /C "Operational mode                  = %mode%"
') do Set "value2=%%a"
echo no files, find   : value2=[%value2%]

rem with no auxiliary files, no `for` loop
set "value2="
netsh firewall show state|findstr /R "Operational.mode.*=.%mode%$">NUL
set /A "value2=-(%errorlevel%-1)"
echo no files, no loop: value2=[%value2%]
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\33668356.bat Enable
 2 files, find   : value2=[1]
no files, find   : value2=[1]
no files, no loop: value2=[1]

==> D:\bat\SO\33668356.bat Disable
 2 files, find   : value2=[0]
no files, find   : value2=[0]
no files, no loop: value2=[0]

==>
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~1`, `%%a` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`>`, `>NUL`, `|` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- (`^|` etc. special page) [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)